# Static function without return type can pass compile on Windows but not on Linux

Tags: c++, g++, mingw-w64

I have a class containing a static function which doesn't declare the return type (Yes, I forgot...), **the code can be successfully compiled on Windows**. However, when I try to compile on my Arch Linux laptop, it gave me following error.

`error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'bar' with no type [-fpermissive]`

I tried to compile the codes using `-Wall -fno-permissive` flags on Windows, but it still pass the compilation and **without any warning**. That's so weird...

```
Mingw Version:
g++.exe (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0

Compiler Information:
GNU C++14 (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) version 8.1.0 (x86_64-w64-mingw32)
    compiled by GNU C version 8.1.0, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 4.0.1, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.18-GMP

Default Flags:
 -iprefix C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/
 -D_REENTRANT .\Test0\hello.c -mtune=core2 -march=nocona
options enabled:  -faggressive-loop-optimizations
 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fauto-inc-dec -fchkp-check-incomplete-type
 -fchkp-check-read -fchkp-check-write -fchkp-instrument-calls
 -fchkp-narrow-bounds -fchkp-optimize -fchkp-store-bounds
 -fchkp-use-static-bounds -fchkp-use-static-const-bounds
 -fchkp-use-wrappers -fcommon -fdelete-null-pointer-checks -fdwarf2-cfi-asm
 -fearly-inlining -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fexceptions
 -ffp-int-builtin-inexact -ffunction-cse -fgcse-lm -fgnu-runtime
 -fgnu-unique -fident -finline-atomics -fira-hoist-pressure
 -fira-share-save-slots -fira-share-spill-slots -fivopts
 -fkeep-inline-dllexport -fkeep-static-consts -fleading-underscore
 -flifetime-dse -flto-odr-type-merging -fmath-errno -fmerge-debug-strings
 -fpeephole -fpic -fplt -fprefetch-loop-arrays -freg-struct-return
 -fsched-critical-path-heuristic -fsched-dep-count-heuristic
 -fsched-group-heuristic -fsched-interblock -fsched-last-insn-heuristic
 -fsched-rank-heuristic -fsched-spec -fsched-spec-insn-heuristic
 -fsched-stalled-insns-dep -fschedule-fusion -fsemantic-interposition
 -fset-stack-executable -fshow-column -fs
hrink-wrap-separate -fsigned-zeros
 -fsplit-i
vs-in-unroller -fssa-backprop -fstdarg-opt
 -fstrict-volatile-bitfields -fsync-libcalls -ftrapping-math -ftree-cselim
 -ftree-forwprop -ftree-loop-if-convert -ftree-loop-im -ftree-loop-ivcanon
 -ftree-loop-optimize -ftree-parallelize-loops= -ftree-phiprop
 -ftree-reassoc -ftree-scev-cprop -funit-at-a-time -funwind-tables
 -fvar-tracking -fvar-tracking-assignments -fzero-initialized-in-bss
 -m128bit-long-double -m64 -m80387 -maccumulate-outgoing-args
 -malign-double -malign-stringops -mcx16 -mfancy-math-387 -mfentry
 -mfp-ret-in-387 -mfxsr -mieee-fp -mlong-double-80 -mmmx -mms-bitfields
 -mno-sse4 -mpush-args -mred-zone -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mstack-arg-probe
 -mstackrealign -mvzeroupper
```

Following is the example code:

```
class Foo {
public:
    static bar(int a)
    {
        int ret;
        /* Do some stuff... */
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Why the mingw compiler wouldn't detect the error?

Comment: Are you actually sure that code is being compiled in mingw and isn't `#ifdef`'ed out or something?

Comment: @NikosC. The original codes is very simple, it doesn't have any external includes or define something.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Mingw is able to detect the return type automatically (int).

But in any case this code does not conform to the C++ standard and should not be used.

if necessary, you can use **auto** as return type like

```
class Foo {
public:
    static auto bar(int a)
    {
        int ret;
        /* Do some stuff... */
        return ret;
    }
};
```

This is correct for any compiler that supports С++14